# jQuery multiple pagination system with "show more" button

Tags: jquery, pagination

I would like to create a pagination with a "`show more`" button.

I created a tab system. With a pagination system in each tab (`.pagination-zone`).

The problem is that the two paginations are in conflict.

For example there are 3 items displayed in the first tab and nothing in the second tab.

So I tried to use `each` function with `$(this)` for the context.

```
$('.pagination-zone').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var itemsCount = 0;
    var itemsElement = that.find('.pagination-list .pagination-item');
    var itemsMax = itemsElement.length;

    itemsElement.hide();

    function showNextItems() {
        var pagination = 3;

        for (var i = itemsCount; i < (itemsCount + pagination); i++) {
            that.find('.pagination-list .pagination-item:eq(' + i + ')').show();
        }

        itemsCount += pagination;

        if (itemsCount > itemsMax) {
            that.find('.pagination-button').hide();
        }
    };

    showNextItems();

    that.find('.pagination-more').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        showNextItems();
    });
});
```

What's wrong please ?

Comment: Could you please make a reproducible example so that it can be tested?